# focus on dynamic input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box which dynamially creates rows of html for search results.

I am attempting to focus on the first element via jquery but something is not working

```
var inputEl = $('#stock-results input[name=quantity]:first');

inputEl.focus();

inputEl.css({ border: "solid 1px #ff6633", padding: "20px" }).focus();
```

i can see that the style of the input box is changing as indicates above, but i just cant get the cursor to focus on the input box;

any ideas?

EDIT:

BTW, thi only happens the first time i search, if I search again it focuses fine. Also i noticed if i add an alert after the focus call, then when i close the alert the focus goes in the correct element

Comment: can you provide some of your markup for this issue

Comment: Post a complete code example please so that we can reproduce the problem. In addition, a snippet in your question or a link to a jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: I put a fiddle together, the behavior works with the provided code snippet you've given us.. so the issue seems to be related to some other aspect of your code.. probably the 'dynamic' aspect you've referenced in your question.. but have not provided a sample to.. as of yet: http://jsfiddle.net/bcaswell/hzgqmpz3/

Comment: it's also worth noting that when `input` elements receive **focus**, it is there `outline` style declaration that toggles on and off.. if I remember correctly, firefox puts the outline at the outter edge of padding/margining, and webkit (chrome safari) - and I think IE - disregard the margining.. so there's a little inconsistency in that appearance. if you're going to be altering the border appearance to determine focus, I would recommend setting `outline` to `0`